# How do mirror prox and accelerated methods differ conceptually?

Tags: divergence-operator, gradient-descent, convergence-acceleration

In the very basic case of nice function on Hilbert space, dual space is same as primal, it seems to me that they to almost same thing: at point $x_t$ they apply a gradient obtained by looking "one step ahead" $x_{t+1} = x_t + \eta \nabla f(x_t + \eta \nabla f(x_t))$. Mirror prox adds an additional restriction on closeness of both "look ahead" and "gradient step" points in terms of some divergence:

$$ \hat z_t = \arg\min_z (D(z, z_t) + \langle \eta \nabla f(z_t), z \rangle)$$
$$ z_{t+1} = \arg\min_z (D(z, z_t) + \langle \eta \nabla f(\hat z_t), z \rangle)$$

Does the divergence-closeness part is the only difference? Should they perform similarly in saddle point problems without constraints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen it referred to as a "mirror prox", however I know that *D-resolvents* can be viewed as a generalization of a proximal operator for when you re-define your distance in a Hilbert space. These notions of distance are also known as "Bregman divergences," and capture the KL-divergence as a special case. When you use the distance $\|z-z_t\|^2/2$, the D-resolvent reduces to the "standard" proximal operator. All of the basic properties for proximal operators have analogies for D-resolvents, and THE paper on this subject is by Bauschke, Borwein and Combettes. [Here is a free version.](https://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/sicon2.pdf)

Also, examples of proxes for when you redefine your distance can be found, e.g., [here](http://proximity-operator.net/scalarfunctions.html#bregman).